# Passing parameters between Processors, beans etc., in Camel

Tags: parameters

I have a situation as mentioned below

Consider my below Route defined for instance

```
from("file:SOURCE/data?noop=true")
    .bean(Bean1.class, "someMethod")
    .process(someProcessorBean1)
    .bean(Bean1.class, "someMethod")
    .bean(ServiceBean.class, "serviceMethod")
    .process(someProcessorBean2)
    .bean(ServiceBean2.class, "serviceMethod2")
    .bean(Bean1.class, "someMethod")
    .process(someProcessorBean3)
    .bean(Bean1.class, "someMethod")
```

I am using Bean1's `someMethod()` for getting some parameters in Hashmap which is set in different processors which i will be using for some other purpose.

I am able to set a Hashmap in camel context as below

```
getContext().setProperties(contextMap);
```

and I am able to retrieve the same in Bean1 as follows

```
exchange.getContext().getProperties();
```

Now, the hashmap available in  the `getContext()` is `Map<String,String>` and THAT IS NOT the Properties Map which we can access through @Properties in the method parameter.
I want to set in `Map<Object,Object>` which can be accessible @Properties param.

How do we set the Properties (@Properties) which accepts `Map<Object,Object>`?

Comment: exchange.getProperties()  - will give Properties set for Camel Context which accepts Map<String,Object>